# Angular testing router spy with then property in Jasmine framework

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have used routing navigation like this in the ts file as

```
onSearch(searchValue) {
        if (searchValue !== "") {
            this.router
                .navigateByUrl("/", { skipLocationChange: true })
                .then(() =>
                    this.router.navigate(["/test"], { queryParams: { searchValue } })
                );
        }
    }
```

And in spec.ts file

```
describe('HomeComponent', () => {
  let component: HomeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HomeComponent>;
  let de: DebugElement;
  let el: HTMLElement;
  let router: Router;
  let location: Location;
  let mockRouter;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([{ path: 'test', component: HomeComponent }, { path: 'search', component: HomeComponent },
        { path: 'providers', component: HomeComponent }])
        , ToastrModule.forRoot()
      ],
      declarations: [HomeComponent]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
    location = TestBed.inject(Location);
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    de = fixture.debugElement;
    fixture.detectChanges();

  });

it('test search text for provider and work post', fakeAsync(() => {
    const spy = spyOn(router,'navigateByUrl').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(true));
    component.onSearch("Web");
    fixture.detectChanges();
    debugger;
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/test');
     }
  ));
)}
```

Then running it, I got errors like

Expected spy navigateByUrl to have been called with:
['/test'] but actual calls were:
[ '/', Object({ skipLocationChange: true }) ].

Answer (score 0):

In the `onSearch(searchValue)` method you're calling `navigateByUrl("/", { skipLocationChange: true })`, so the test is correctly failing and logging that it expected `[ '/', Object({ skipLocationChange: true }) ].`

You have added a `test` route to the `RouterTestingModule`, but your app doesn't use that route

Comment: I tried to write expect(spy).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith('/test'); but there are no such type of property found.

Answer (score 0):

The method you are spying on is "navigateByUrl"....
try to spy on "navigate" and then you could check if it is called or not.